# What to do when a module depend on a specific version and you are running the latest dev version of it

Tags: updating

What is the best practice for working with module one, that depends on 7.x-1.1 (or better) of module two and you are running the latest dev version module two.

I ask this because currently scheduler_workbench depends on scheduler 7.x-1.1 or better and I am running the latest development version of scheduler. If I try to install scheduler_workbench it prevent me from installing it. When I try to do a database update, it complains about the version and prevents update database from running (though I can update the database through drush still).

I could easily add 7.x-1.1 into scheduler info file and everything is good.  However, I do not feel this is the best option.   The version is not correct and if I update the module it will remove the version number.